# What is an example of use case for epsilon in dart petitparser?

Tags: dart, petitparser

I don't understand the comment:

```dart
/// Returns a parser that consumes nothing and succeeds.
///
/// For example, `char('a').or(epsilon())` is equivalent to
/// `char('a').optional()`.
@useResult
Parser<void> epsilon() => epsilonWith<void>(null);
```

Could someone give a specific example?

Comment: The best answer I've found to deep petitparser questions is to study the tests, or study the examples repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to do exactly what it says.  Instead of writing "foo = optional bar" you can define a step with "foo = bar or epsilon".

In the "indent" parser in the repo, I see it is used to attach .where and .map options with side-effects.  You can [check that out](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/blob/235fd022867f36e726cb7c7c880782a8af5b3f67/lib/src/indent/indent.dart#L52C43-L52C43) for details.